# Django F Date Expresion generated from static field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, python-datetime

I am trying to get a series of ages from a persons list, but the age generated change with each query because is the  age in a specific event so i can accomplish this with a simple loop, extracting the timedelta from the diference:

```
 [ (event_date - user.birth_date).days/365.25 for user in User.objects.all() ]
```

event_date is always a datatime.date object anr user.birth_date too. I consider it a "Static"
field or constant because it is outside the database.

This gives me the correct results, but since I am doing this many times and i have other calculations to do I wanted to generate the ages from the database using the F() expresion.

```
``from django.db.models import  ExpressionWrapper, fields

    diference = ExpressionWrapper(
    event_date- F('birth_date'),
    output_field=fields.DurationField())

qs_ages= self.annotate(age_dist=diference)
```

this should give me a field named age_dist that will be a timedelta contains the total days between the two dates, so now I should do this and should give me the same result as above.

[ user.age_dist.days/365.25 for user in User.objects.all() ]

But this does not work, the result is a time delta of microseconds
What i am doing wrong? and how should I include the static value of event_date to the expression?

And... going beyond. Is there any way to get the days of the resultant time delta from the ExpressionWrapper?

Answer (score 0):

since you're doing the operation on a datetime object it'll return you a datetime object which is converted to timedelta microseconds when you use DurationField as an the output field.
you can workaround this by doing everything in the database :

```
age = ExpressionWrapper(
            Cast((event_date.date() - F('birth_date')) / 365.25 ,output_field=fields.PositiveIntegerField()), 
            output_field=fields.PositiveIntegerField()
            )
```